# python slicing too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas

When I print klines:

```
    [[1619049600000, '0.00051058', '0.00051244', '0.00050393', '0.00050537', '358947.00000000', 1619051399999, '182.48971859', 631, '183371.00000000', '93.30896094', '0'], [1619051400000, '0.00050498', '0.00050855', '0.00049703', '0.000497
        76', '398485.00000000', 1619053199999, '199.73218470', 713, '127770.00000000', '64.11581916', '0'], [1619053200000, '0.00049790', '0.00050368', '0.00049673', '0.00050101', '277808.00000000', 1619054999999, '138.96987840', 415, '227353.
        00000000', '113.70332258', '0'], [1619055000000, '0.00050109', '0.00050386', '0.00050023', '0.00050361', '75878.00000000', 1619056799999, '38.12508965', 205, '51987.00000000', '26.13164503', '0'], 
.
.
.
.

 [1619071200000, '0.00049466', '0.00049748', '0.00049123', '0.00049312', '333336.00000000', 1619072999999, '164.79262458', 51
        7, '207514.00000000', '102.65957752', '0'], [1619073000000, '0.00049307', '0.00049611', '0.00048943', '0.00049175', '384695.00000000', 1619074799999, '189.31415578', 600, '217779.00000000', '107.25268087', '0'], [1619074800000, '0.0004
        9179', '0.00049520', '0.00049042', '0.00049186', '205773.00000000', 1619076599999, '101.37660066', 421, '131255.00000000', '64.67154003', '0'], [1619076600000, '0.00049199', '0.00049600', '0.00048986', '0.00049291', '138476.00000000',
        1619078399999, '68.23478437', 335, '80214.00000000', '39.57997596', '0']]
```

when I only print closings without slicing:

```
[[1.61905140e+12 4.07930000e-02 4.11480000e-02 4.02930000e-02
  4.03010000e-02 9.13340000e+02 1.61905320e+12 3.71116299e+01
  1.20000000e+02 4.16740000e+02 1.69594809e+01 0.00000000e+00]
 [1.61905320e+12 4.03030000e-02 4.09150000e-02 4.02670000e-02
  4.05260000e-02 1.41594000e+03 1.61905500e+12 5.74293609e+01
  1.15000000e+02 5.15780000e+02 2.09728155e+01 0.00000000e+00]
 .
 .
 .
 .
 [1.61907840e+12 3.86210000e-02 3.86210000e-02 3.86210000e-02
  3.86210000e-02 9.38000000e+00 1.61908020e+12 3.62264980e-01
  1.00000000e+00 9.38000000e+00 3.62264980e-01 0.00000000e+00]]
```

code:

```
 while True:
    rsi_values = []
    for SYMBOL in SYMBOLS:
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(SYMBOL + 'ETH', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_30MINUTE,
                                              '{} hours ago UTC'.format((RSI_N + 3) // 2))

        closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1:, 4]

        diffs = np.diff(closings)
        ups = diffs.clip(min=0)
        downs = diffs.clip(max=0)

        ups = pd.DataFrame(ups)
        downs = pd.DataFrame(downs)

        ups_avg = ups.ewm(span=RSI_N).mean()
        downs_avg = downs.ewm(span=RSI_N).mean()

        rs = ups_avg / downs_avg
        rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
        rsi_values.append((SYMBOL, rsi))
```

error:

```
    closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1:, 4]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I've originally had errors with pd.ewm Because I wrote like pd.ewm(ups.span=RSI_N)[-1]
And after I solved the pandas problem, the slicing error I haven't had occured. RSI_N is 14

Can anyone help me ? I really need some help.

Comment: closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1, 4]

Extra colon....removed...

Comment: Than it would raise value error from diff

raise ValueError("diff requires input that is at least one dimensional")
ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional

Comment: removing colon would return only one value which is int

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the heterogeneity of the data doesn't like to numpy.
np.asarray must create an array of 2 dimensions hopefully:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
np.asarray(a, dtype=float).shape
```

You can verify if all data are correctly interpreted from numpy with the following code:

```
for row in a:
    print(np.asarray(row, dtype=float).shape)
```

are all of the same length, type and so on

if so try to stack each row:

```
np.stack([np.asarray(row, dtype=float) for row in a]).shape
```